# Elasticsearch - Match long query text to short field

Tags: elasticsearch

Standard match involves providing a small query term or phrase and matching it against a larger blob of text stored in a document. I want to do the reverse - my query will be a large blob of text, like a paragraph, and I want to rank the relevance of documents that contain a full name (i.e. John Smith). I want to supply a paragraph and determine which document's full name is most likely to be contained in that paragraph. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: The Percolate API allows you to store queries and run documents against them: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html